# Is there a way to simulate DNS Hijacking for testing purposes?

Tags: windows, dns

I'm working on an application that connects to URLs, and it responds differently depending on whether or not an address resolves in DNS.  I need to find a way to simulate DNS Hijacking so that I can test that my application handles it correctly.

Anybody know a way to do that?

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: please describe esactly what you want to do to test.  I can think of a few solutions, but I'm not sure that they line up with your thought process.

Comment: Daniel if the question is reformatted ever so slightly it can easily be programming related.  Security is, rather should be, a large piece of the sdlc

Comment: I want to take a computer that's on a network that involves no DNS Hijacking.  And I want to somehow modify the computer so that DNS Hijacking does happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a DNS Server on a second pc and use this as your referenced DNS. Then you can shutdown it for sometime or modify the answers to try your handling behavior. If you dont have a second machine you can also set it up in a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did.  I still want to dive in and figure out how to make a wildcard DNS entry that leads the user to a page that depends on what they entered (i.e. how ISPs do it, where it leads to their search engine with the URL as a query).  But that's a separate problem (purely a "How do I do this on this server?" problem).

Comment: Actually I do not know how to do this. Maybe you need some kind of open dns service, in which you can specify a handler for unresolved URLs. I never tried this before on Windows Server environment.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the "hijacked" hosts into your `hosts` file. In Linux, this should be in `/etc/hosts`; in Windows, `%SYSTEMDIR%\drivers\etc\hosts.`.

The entries are in the format `ip.addr.ess.here    hostname1 hostname2` (there should already be entries for localhost, so add others to match your taste)

When you're done, remove (or comment out) from the `hosts` file again.